# How to do a live binding of a click handler in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a click event handler that looks like this:

```
$('#show_existing_suggestions').click(function()
```

But after some AJAX calls, it is no longer recognized by jQuery.  Is there a way to do a live binding of that click handler?  I think the reshuffling of the HTML is messing it up.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#show_existing_suggestions').live('click', function() { ... });
```

As of jQuery 1.7, `live()` has been deprecated (thanks [Vikk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/885119/vikk)). Use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Comment: that just gave me an unexpected token error - are you sure its right?  Here is what I had: $('#show_existing_suggestions').live('click' function() {

Comment: the error happens as this page loads: http://www.problemio.com/problems/problem.php?problem_id=218

Comment: You're missing the comma after click.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder you mean on like this: $('#show_existing_suggestions').on('click' , function() {

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder good to know.  For me it gave an error..maybe cause I am using a previous version of jQuery, but the live thing did fix it!!  Thanks to all!

Comment: @Genadinik the .on() sample you provided in the comments will not work as a live binding. I'll provide an explanation as an answer, though I in no way expect you to change whose answer you accepted. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#show_existing_suggestions').live('click',function(){});
```

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `.on()` (1.7 forward), then to reproduce this as a "live" binding, you need to call it on the document, not on the clickable element:

```
$(document).on('click', '#show_existing_suggestions', function() { ... });
```

But since you're already this far along, you should take it a step further and delegate not to the document but to an ancestor more deeply nested if possible. The syntax is the same, the selector is different:

```
$('#someElement').on('click', '#show_existing_suggestions', function() { ... });
```

Where `#someElement` is any ancestor of `show_existing_suggestions` that you do not forsee ever being destroyed. Could conceivably be the next element up in the tree, but it could be a section wrapper or even page wrapper (what site these days doesn't have a page wrapper?)